# Get all screen names from Twitter without hitting rate limit

Tags: twitter

I have successfully gotten a bunch of Twitter user_ids using the Twitter API resource "[GET friends/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids)".

I need to be able to get all screen names from Twitter without hitting the rate limit. I know I can use "[GET friendships/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friendships/show)" to get the "screen_name", but to do that, I would have to loop through all of the user_ids, each one being a request, thereby potentially hitting the rate limit.

Does anyone know of a way to send an array of user_ids, in one request? Or... any other ideas or methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) API?  I believe you can send a list of upto 100 userids in one request and it will send back a fair bit of info about each one, including their last tweet.  As it says in the docs

> It's also well suited for use in tandem with friends/ids and followers/ids.

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Wow. Thanks John. I looked at that array maybe 5 to 10 times and never noticed the screen_name being returned. Blind as a bat.